# How to make a link in HTML with href as its content

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I think it is clear but here is an example:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">https://stackoverflow.com/</a>
```

The code makes this real link: https://stackoverflow.com/

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: What kind of "simpler"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: if "href" was a variable in any other language (of course not in HTML), we would for example write <a href="____.com/">@href</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you want something like:

```
<a>http://stackoverflow.com/</a>
```

That would look logical, but what if you want to have custom text, eg POTATO?

This would make no sense.

```
<a>POTATO</a>
```

*The text in the link is really just the clickable text, not where the link points to.* Also, you can have image in the link, or other things. The `href` attribute is what really matters in HTML.

This is right:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a>
<a href="http://potato.com/">POTATO</a>
```

To do something like what you want, the best option is to use some kind of pre-processor, like BBCode parser (BBCode is the format used on bulletin boards).

In BBCode, you could have

```
[url]http://stackoverflow.com/[/url]
```

translate to

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a>
```

Note that BBCode also allows

```
[url=http://stackoverflow.com]Link text[/url]
```

or, with the potato example

```
[url=http://potato.com]POTATO[/url]
```

You can make your own parser that does something similar with regular expressions, eg. using `preg_replace`.

Comment: mmm, That's nice, so a pre-processor, like BBCode is a must in the case of HTML,

Comment: Well depends on what you want, but if this is to convert eg. articles to html for display, some kind of processing is a good idea. Also check out Markdown, it doesn't do exactly this, but is really nice, I use it for my blog.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. You have to specify `href` attribute for link to lead somewhere. What you write between `<a>` tag is not related to actual link (href)

Answer (score 1):

Simply using Jquery you can as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).attr("href"))
      })
    })
  </script>
```

In this solution you just have to write your hyperlink code as `<a href="http://foo.com"></a>` and then the code above will set `http://foo.com` as the link's text.

Checkout this Demo: http://jsbin.com/hajobewixu/1/

Comment: this is really useful, I'll definitely use it!

Comment: This will work, but bots and people with javascript disabled will not see the link (bots will see link, but no text in it, people won't see anything), that's quite a big drawback imo.

Comment: it's true, although I think these days most websites get scrambled when JS is disabled

Comment: For this purpose you have to use a server-side scripting solution that mainly will depend on regular expressions or [tag:xpath]

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` HTML element denotes an anchor and it is used for both ends of the link. If it has the `name` attribute then it can be used as a destination for a link. This is useful for tables of contents f.e.; the links in a TOC points to various sections inside the page. The `href` attribute is used to mark the `<a>` element as a source of a link.

Example (TOC)

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#chapter1">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter2">Blah, blah, blah</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter3">Conclusion</a></li>
</ul>


<h1><a name="chapter1">Introduction</a></h1>
<p>Some text here</a>

<h1><a name="chapter2">Blah, blah, blah</a></h1>
<p>Some other text here</a>

<h1><a name="chapter3">Conclusion</a></h1>
<p>No, there is no simpler way to specify a link.</a>
```

If you write just `<a>something here</a>` the browser should have to guess what do you want to achieve: a link source or a destination? (Note that an `<a>` element that have both `href` and `name` attributes is a source and also a destination). Since the valid values of both `name` and `href` attributes follow some rules, most of the time it is not possible to guess them from the content of the `<a>` element. **And this is not the way HTML works, anyway.**

#### Short answer to your question:

No, in HTML this is not possible. You can use [`Markdown`](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), [`Textile`](http://redcloth.org/hobix.com/textile/) or other text-processing languages to write less markup; the documents written in these languages need to be pre-processed and converted to HTML before they can be published.

Comment: ok, so it's really clear that a source and a destination are two different things, so they should be separated and get two different values, Thank's axiac